# addClass() to specific elements within a containing wrapper

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, jquery-hover

I have been wracking my brains as to how to achieve this. I have a containing element, which has two separate `a` tags within it that I want to `addClass()` to (i.e. when I hover over one `a` tag, it adds the class to that one, and the other `a` tag within that containing element). I kind of had it by using the below code:

```
<li class="element">
<header>
   <h1>Heading</h1>
</header>
   <a href="">
      <img src="image" alt=" dummy" />
   </a>
   <div>
      <h2><a href="">Heading 2</a></h2>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
   </div>
</li>

$('.element').hover(
 function() {
  $(this).children().addClass('hover');
},
 function() {
  $(this).children().removeClass('hover');
}
);
```

However I only want the hover triggered when on the 'a' itself, not on the entire element. Unfortunately, when I use this method:

```
$('.element a').hover(
 function() {
  $(this).addClass('hover');
},
 function() {
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
}
);
```

It only adds the class to the first 'a' tag.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not use the css selector `a:hover` ? example usage here -> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: I can't use the hover function as I need the class to be triggered on  all a elements even when I'm hovering on one.

Comment: understood - removed my answer

Comment: update my answer, I think thats what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.element a').hover(
 function() {
  $(this).add($(this).siblings()).addClass('hover');
},
 function() {
  $(this).add($(this).siblings()).removeClass('hover');
}
);
```

$(this) only contains the actual object being hovered. I .add()-ed the siblings of the object to that set, you can filter it with $(this).siblings('a') or similar, if you prefer.

Comment: This is almost there! The only problem is when you hover on the a, it applies the hover to the div, and not the a within it. I tried specifying the $(this).siblings('a') solution but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the addClass to each element ... try this :

```
$('.element a').each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(".element a").each(function() {
            $(this).addClass('hover');
        });
    }, function() {
        $(".element a").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hover');
        });

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/GqP4Z/

Comment: Not quite - that adds the class to every '.element a' on the page, not that specific list item.

Comment: @Michael on the question you didnt mention there were multiple divs with the class element ?!?!?!

Comment: apologies - I'd thought as it was a list element that it would indicate multiple elements but I should be more specific. I think the answer below is really close to what I need but just can't get the nested 'a' tags.